# How to tell if it's a Moishezon morphism

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry, several-complex-variables

Suppose that $f \colon X\rightarrow S$ is a proper morphism of reduced and irreducible complex spaces and $f$ is a smooth deformation in the sense of Kodaira and Spencer.  If we know each fiber $X_s$, $s\in S$ is a Moishezon manifold, can we conclude $f \colon X\rightarrow S$ is a Moishezon morphism?  Here Moishezon morphism is defined as following: $f$ is called Moishezon if $f$ is bimeromorphic to a locally projective morphism $g\colon Y\rightarrow S$.

Comment: The morphism $f$ need not be Moishezon. One example is when $X$ is a Hopf surface, $(\mathbb{C}^2 \setminus\{(0,0)\})/\sim$ with $(x,y)\sim(qx,qy)$ for a nonzero complex number $q$ of modulus $\neq 1$.  The target $S$ is $\mathbb{CP}^1 = (\mathbb{C}^2\setminus\{(0,0)\})/\mathbb{C}^\times$, and every fiber of $f$ is isomorphic to the elliptic curve $E=\mathbb{C}^\times/q^{\mathbb{Z}}$.  All of the fibers are Moishezon, but the morphism is not Moishezon.

Comment: @JS: how does one prove that $f$ is not Moishezon?

Comment: @JS: Also, is the conclusion not compatible with HassanJolany's answer below or am I missing something?

Comment: You are missing something. Hassan Jolany tells you that $f$ is *locally* Moishezon, over any small neighborhood of a point in $S$. This is much weaker than being globally Moishezon. In the example of Jason Starr the fibration is even locally trivial. If this $f$ were Moishezon, the Hopf surface would be Moishezon, which it is not.

Answer (score 1):

A Moishezon manifold $M$ is a compact complex manifold such that the field of meromorphic functions on each component $M$ has transcendence degree equal the complex dimension of the component: $\dim_\mathbf{C}M=a(M)=\operatorname{tr.deg.}_\mathbf{C}\mathbf{C}(M).$

> Let $\pi: X\to S$ be a proper morphism of complex spaces. If $\pi$ is
>   a Moishezon morphism, i.e., bimeromorphic over $S$ to a projective
>   morphism then each fiber of $\pi$ is a Moishezon space. Conversely, if
>   $\pi$ is smooth and each fiber is Moishezon, then for every $s \in S$
>   there exists a neighborhood set $U$ such that $\pi|_U$ is Moishezon
>
> See, Akira FUJIKI, Deformation of Uniruled Manifolds , Publ. RIMS,
>   Kyoto Univ. 17 (1981), 687-702.

Comment: Daniel Barlet recently showed(there is anoher proof also by Dan Popovici http://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~esiprpr/esi2238.pdf) that Let $ \pi : X \to S$ a proper surjective map between irreducible complex spaces.  Let $S^∗$ be a dense Zariski open set in $S$. Assume that for each $s ∈ S^∗$ the fiber $ X_s $of $π$ at $s$ are Moishezon, then the central fibre $X_0$ is Moishezon  https://arxiv.org/pdf/1705.01743.pdf

Comment: I have not been able to find a proof of the (second part of the) statement of the answer in the literature. The paper [Fujiki, Deformation of Uniruled Manifolds] refers to [Fujiki, Relative algebraic reduction and relative Albanese map...] where I unfortunately could not find a proof. Did I miss something ?